# Return from OnCompleteListener with Kotlin Lambda

Tags: firebase, lambda, kotlin

I want to get some return values when a onCompleteListener is successful, but with Kotlin and lambdas I don't get it. I read this [doc](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression) .

I'm using this onCompleteListener to get data from FireStore/Firebase.

I have this function:

```
fun getRegisters() : MutableList<Register> {

       mRegistersFirestoreRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(

                OnCompleteListener { task ->

                    when {
                        task.isSuccessful -> {

                            val documents = task.result

                            var registerList : MutableList<Register> = mutableListOf()

                            for (document: QueryDocumentSnapshot in documents) {

                                registerList.add(document.toObject(Register::class.java))
                            }

                            return@OnCompleteListener registerList

                        }
                        else -> {
                            Log.e("Error", task.exception)
                        }
                    }
                }) 
}
```

When I write

```
return@OnCompleteListener registerList
```

IDE said Require Unit.

I understand I must return Unit to respect the order function and because the lambda is inside OnCompleteListener, but I want to return the list that I get from the OnCompleteListener.

Comment: You won't be able to directly return the list synchronously which you received in a callback.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Do everything you need to do in the callback itself.  It might help to read up on techniques for asynchronous programming in Java - the same will apply to Kotlin.

Comment: @DougStevenson please can you give me some more specific answer or some doc that helps?. Thank you.

Comment: There is no specific answer, because what you do depends highly on your chosen app architecture.  It's a very broad issue.

Comment: Well there are about 6 different ways to solve this issue with varying levels of involvement/complexity, but the simplest solution is to pass in a callback to `getRegisters()` instead of assuming that it'd return the list synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a Firebase environment, so I can't test my code. But, as of the Kotlin grammar, I think you can pull `registerList` out of the Lambda scope, like this:

```
fun getRegisters() : MutableList<Register> {
    var registerList : MutableList<Register> = mutableListOf()
    mRegistersFirestoreRef.get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            OnCompleteListener { task ->
                when {
                    task.isSuccessful -> {
                        val documents = task.result
                        for (document: QueryDocumentSnapshot in documents) {
                            registerList.add(document.toObject(Register::class.java))
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.e("Error", task.exception)
                    }
                }
            })
    return registerList
}
```

or use `with` or `apply` to "simplify" the call of `var something = initial(); doSth(something); return something` into `return with (initial()) { doSth(this); this }` or `return initial().apply { doSth(this) }` (However, this may be slightly out of the question scope).

Comment: Thank you but, I think this won't work, because a I need the return inside of listener. Imagine you have a OnClickListener and the function should return the list when a user press the button that activate the listener. If i put the return outside it will never be reachable.